# Фиксированная навигация

Tags: javascript, html, css

Написал код чтобы когда скрол браузера достигает определённой позиции, навигация прилипала к верху

Проблема в том что при прокрутке навбар дрыгается и липнет то к верху то к низу...Помогите исправить код пожалуйста

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var nav = $('.navbar');
  if (nav.offset().top > 780) {
    nav.addClass('fixed-top');
    nav.css({
      "background-color": "#red"
    });
  } else {
    nav.removeClass('fixed-top');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Нельзя пересчитывать `.offset().top` у элемента который фиксируется, он будет всегда разным, отсюда и ваша проблема. Оберните чем-то, что будет всегда оставаться на своем месте (контейнеру нужен будет задавать высоту, что бы страница не скакала.

Comment: а как можно переписать, чтобы действие актевировалось, когда окно касается определённого класса?

Comment: у этого блока фиксированная высота?

Comment: ну я поставил размер 80vh

Comment: добавьте сss так ничего не понятно